# Where can I find a list of MRI scanners ordered by the quality of the images they take?

Tags: mri, medical-imaging

I'd like to have a list of MRI scanners ordered by the quality of the images they take. The number of teslas is one parameter, but among MRI scanners with the same number it teslas, I'm told the image quality quality varies a lot between different MRI scanners. For example, I was told by several radiologists that the recently released GE Sina Premier MRI scanner had better image quality than the GE Discovery MRI scanner. If that depends on which type of tissue is being analyzed, I'm mostly interested in tendons.

I searched on Google and Google Scholar but couldn't find any information on it yet beyond what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be, "Where can I find data on MRI image quality so I can construct a list of MRIs ordered by quality?" There's no apparent prior research here other than anecdotal comments from unnamed individuals.

Comment: Another key issue is what your definition of quality is. I'm not a radiologist, but I strongly suspect that different scanners will have strengths and weaknesses with regards to pulse sequences. While one model might be very good at crisp T2 weighted images, it may struggle with diffusion weighted images. I think as written (in addition to not having any prior research), the question is too broad.

Comment: @IanCampbell thanks, the ranking could be indeed divided into different factors. But there seems to be some clear order at times, eg GE Sina Premier > GE Discovery. I did searched quite a bit on Google but didn't find anything aside from an old research gate discussion that linked to some potentially interesting but 404 website. I'll try to find it again and see what the way back medicine contains, but it won't contain the recently released scanners. Note I mentioned that my main interest was tendon analysis, which should make the ranking even clearer ie the question even narrower by the way

Comment: @IanCampbell I found the discussion and  added the website as an answer as it's a good starting point.

Comment: Adding an answer isn't prior research. The question remains closable.

Comment: @CareyGregory how do you want me to demonstrate prior research, when I haven't found anything except for the imperfect answer?

Comment: I don't know, Frank. That's for you to figure out. You have three credible links in your answer and zero in your question, which were posted three hours apart. I find it hard to believe you can't make your question meet site standards.

Comment: @CareyGregory added.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Evelio González Dalmau mentions on https://www.researchgate.net/post/MRI_MRS_users_what_is_your_opinion_the_best_machine_3T:

> the website: http://www.magnet-mri.org/. In a quantitative assessment is made of the parameters and characteristics of MRI machines.

Unfortunately the website is discontinued and the latest snapshot I could find on the wayback machine dates back from September 28th 2015:
https://web.archive.org/web/20150928105705/http://magnet-mri.org/ and the tests themselves seem to have stopped in 2009, so it is missing 13 years of advancement in MRI imaging:

> As of the 1st of April 2009 MagNET will no longer be funded by the Centre for Evidence based Purchasing (CEP) to perform evaluations of MRI scanners and applications.

The last message in the Research Gate  discussion dates back from 30th Jul, 2014.